# Typescript - Use generics and parameters values to set a type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like a way to have an interface with a single generic, in which a property is `keyof T` and the other is the proper `T[keyof T]` passed on the first property.

The following code almost meets this requirement, correctly typing the first property (`field`):

```
interface RandomType {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}

type Typer<T = Record<string, any>> = {
    field: keyof T,
    value: T[any]
}

const param: Typer<RandomType> = {
    field: 'baz',
    value: 'foo'
}
```

However, I need to type `value` based on `field`'s value

in the previous example, it should trigger a type error because `RandomType['baz']` is `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Typer<T>` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of field/value pairs for each field in `T`.  You can do this a number of ways.  For example:

```
type Typer<T> = { [K in keyof T]: {
    field: K,
    value: T[K]
} }[keyof T];
```

Here we are [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) the properties in `T` to get a new object whose values are the types you want, and then immediately [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) all its values.

You can verify that `Typer<RandomType>` is what you're looking for:

```
type TyperRandomType = Typer<RandomType>
/* type TyperRandomType = {
    field: "foo";
    value: string;
} | {
    field: "bar";
    value: number;
} | {
    field: "baz";
    value: boolean;
} */
```

and then your example gives the error you expect:

```
const param: Typer<RandomType> = {
    field: 'baz',
    value: 'foo'
}; // error!
// Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEpxAEwPYFsAqAngA4oDeAUMtcjNtgFzIDOYUoA5gNxU0BGcKExABXXH2g8ayAQC8mfegBsIGHgF8KFMCRRFSUADz4AfMgC8yMsgDaAaWShkAawiFsMZPgC6Ta72oYYAglTCY7ABoA5AA3OCURCCZ8e28KdWR1G1d3Tx8ebV0vXSh0LDx9FEtKozKcAl0TCgB6ACpkHVJigzqKostKaSCQsOQAIjpsMakaOISkljZODWQAHyto4dCmMYEoaei5xOExCSgV9cGaLdHduFkD6SOFxWwVNXTkVuatCgRsECsZDEQRwXDJEqGXoNUhmAabYLbZAAcjkyKiT3ixxRk2R6S4yGazWQ0Cg2CgAEIWsTKsxkB5gWSDDoUc9kchBChQP9cCCwMA+CoAHTU7ooZGsdggDjs4B0kDYMAc5jMYAcEBwQUoMDYDpFVHKVQgZFAA)

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you want, but right now you have to specify the key twice:

```
type Typer<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    field: K,
    value: T[K]
}

const param: Typer<RandomType, 'baz'> = {
    field: 'baz',
    value: 'foo' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. ts(2322)
}
```

I think there is an open issue for TS to make it possible to only specify some generics and infer the rest, so that `Typer<RandomType>` would work.

Comment: Probably the most relevant issue on the matter: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242